# What is a Container in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

This is my first question in Stack Overflow. I don't know if this is related to programming or not. But I don't know where to ask.

What is a container in IBM Bluemix? What is the difference between a container and a VM?

And do I need a container if I want to use IBM Bluemix services, such as the iot platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is only indirectly related to programming. For the types of questions to ask on Stack Overflow, see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Stack Overflow help.

The best place for questions about the Bluemix architecture and technology is [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html).

You do not need to use containers to use the Bluemix platform and services, unless you have a specific need for them.

Briefly, Bluemix containers are built on Docker technology. They are a lightweight, portable infrastructure that enable you to run your app without alteration in a variety of runtime environments. They are similar to Virtual Machines, but lightweight in providing only the elements your app requires to run, and portable in being able to run anywhere - Windows, Mac, Linux, or in the cloud. For more details, see [Getting Started with IBM Containers](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_gettingstarted.html#container_ov__docker) in the Bluemix docs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What if i want to combine 2 or more services ? For example, IBM push notification with IBM IoT platform (MQTT). Can I do that without container?

Comment: Yes, you can bind two or more services to the same app.

Answer (score 2):

**In short**:

[Containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization) are virtual software objects that include all of the elements that an app needs to run.

[IBM Containers](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html#container_index) are [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) containers in Bluemix, which is a hosted cloud environment.

Take a look at those links for deeper explanations.